# LINQ Query for ofType in a related property

Tags: linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

How do you filter a LINQ Query by the "OfType" in a related property?

Example: I'm searching the OrderLines collection for orderlines that contain products from a matched list of productIDs. I want to use contains to accomplish this:

```
OrderLines.Where(o => productIDs.contains(o.ProductID))
```

However, I want to only select the orderlines that are related to a SalesOrder, not a Purchase Order. So the `OrderLines.Document` would need to be `ofType<SalesOrder>`

How can I work that into a linq query?

I tried getType but that gets this error:
    "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Type GetType()' method, and         this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter the `Order`s and then their `OrderLine`s:

```
from o in Orders.OfType<SalesOrder>()
from ol in o.OrderLines.Where(ol => productIDs.Contains(ol.ProductID))
```

This is the same as

```
Orders.OfType<SalesOrder>().SelectMany(o =>
      o.OrderLines.Where(ol => productIDs.Contains(ol.ProductID)))
```

Comment: = _productionContext
                .Documents.OfType<SalesOrder>()
                .SelectMany(o => o.Lines).Where(p => productIDs.Contains(p.ProductID)).ToList();

Comment: Correct. Probably generates the same SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

If the situation in question doesn't have an inversion--say, there isn't a navigation property from the "one" to the "many", only the other way, and you're in no place to add it--a similar effect can be achieved using `Contains`.

Suppose for this example, there wasn't a `Lines` property on `Document`.

```
var salesOrders = _productionContext.Documents.OfType<SalesOrder>();
var result = OrderLines.Where(o => 
  productIDs.Contains(o.ProductId) 
  && salesOrders.Contains(o.Document));
```